# disable copy in html style

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to disable copy of `header.value` in this "if"? (if yes, how?)

```html
<div
    class="value"
    style="{{header.name === 'abc' ? 'color: transparent; text-shadow: 0 0 5px black;' : ''}}"
>
    {{ header.value }}
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: As a user of many websites may I just make the point - important, or otherwise - that it genuinely infuriates me when websites do this. Particularly since it's so trivial to work around (view source -> copy, or right-click -> inspect element -> copy). What are you trying to achieve with this (loss of) functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in the css:

```css
.value {
   -moz-user-select: none;  
   -webkit-user-select: none;  
   -ms-user-select: none;  
   -o-user-select: none;  
   user-select: none;
}
```

This would prevent user from selecting the text and copying it.
Sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/small-sea-rseff?file=/index.html

Comment: First, thanks a lot!
I'm looking for cleaner and shorter code
there is another solution?

Comment: hm, you need to take into account of the browser used (Firefox, Chrome, IE etc.), hence the lengthy css